# How to filter an BehaviorSubject array

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to filter on an array that is a BehaviorSubject type and update the value of one of the object properties of the array.

`public users$: BehaviorSubject<IUser[]> = new BehaviorSubject<IUser[]>([]);`

```
 {
        [key:'id',username:'John'],
        [key:'id',username:'David'],
        [key:'id',username:'Sara']
}
```

```
this.breadcrumbs$
            .pipe(
                map(user=> from(user)
                    .pipe(first(x => x.key === key)))
            ).subscribe(res => {
                   const index = this.usersValue.indexOf(res);
                   this.usersValue[index]['username'] = label;
});
```

I want to get it done with **rxjs**

Comment: What's your condition on filtering users$?

Comment: @Joven28 Any condition, Only apply to a property.

Comment: RXJS js has a filter pipe `.pipe(filter(x => {...});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this one.**

```
this.breadcrumbs$.pipe(
   map(users => users.find(user => user.key === key)))
   .subscribe(res => {
       const index = this.usersValue.indexOf(res);
       this.usersValue[index]['username'] = label;
   });
```